# api problems getting nested queries in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a script in python and am accessing an API. I can get some information I need but where I'm stuck is with nested queries. In my code below, first_name needs to equal what would essentially be result[customer->firstname] but I cannot figure out how to get that.

What is the proper syntax to get a nested query like that?

```
Orders-> customer -> firstname

for result in results['orders']:
          order_status_info= self_api.which_api('order_statuses/%d' % result['order_status_id'])
          for customer_blocked_reason in customer_blocked_reasons:
            if customer_blocked_reason in order_status_info['name']:
              customer_is_blocked = True

          order_id            = 0
          order_date          = result['ordered_at']

          first_name          = result [??????]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is result a dict?

You can access nested dictionaries like so:

```
>>> d = {"level1": {"level2": "somedata"}}
>>> d["level1"]["level2"]
'somedata'
```

Comment: @marklar how does `order_date = result['ordered_at']` work on a list? Can you post sample data of the structure.